# What is the relation between geotools and hibernate-spatial ( differences and similarities)

Tags: geotools, hibernate-spatial

I know that hibernate-sapatial is supposed to be an abstraction for the db . And from what i understand there is some kind of possibillity to do that with geotools? ( to what extent i do not know). Someone please clarify this.

Comment: what do you want to do - these are very different products